# Is there a way to limit the time between Twitter searches in node-red?

Tags: twitter, node-red

In node-red, I use a twitter input node (node-red-node-twitter) to search for a specific hashtag. The node continually gives the error "rate limit hit".

According to https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-twitter, *"If you deploy the flows multiple times within a 15 minute window, you may exceed the limit and will see errors from the node. These errors will clear when the current 15 minute window passes."*.
I did not deploy the flow for a much longer time than 15 minutes, still the node gives the error.

When I check the dns queries in my installation of AdGuard Home (which I use as an ad blocker), the device on which node-red is installed makes more than 150000 requests in 24 hours to stream.twitter.com. This seems way too many to me and I can imagine this slows down other network traffic.

I'm not using any other nodes that are search Twitter.

Is there a way to limit the time between the Twitter searches?

Comment: Please edit the question to be specific about which twitter node (there are several listed on flows.nodered.org) you are using. Also just to be clear are you running multiple nodes with different search/hashtags?